# "Contemporary" (as a synonym of "modern") in the context of art and history

Tags: meaning

According to [dictionaries](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/contemporary), *contemporary (adj.)* has a second meaning of *modern; current; of the present age*. Yet in the context of art and history, is usually means *something from the mid-twentieth century*. For example, *contemporary dance* is completely different from dance genres that are popular today. *Contemporary history* explicitly means *post-WWII history*.

Does that mean that the word should be used cautiously in such contexts, or is it just a small number of phrases that include the word (*C. hisory, C. art*) with this special meaning?

Comment: "Does that mean that the word should be used cautiously in such contexts"? Yes.

Comment: Don't miss the point that *contemporary* does **not** mean *modern* by default. It's not really a "secondary meaning" but the meaning relative to the time of mention.

Comment: "Modern" also has this issue in art and philosophy. Lots of periods are actually different ways of saying "new".

Comment: The word 'similar' in a maths lesson shouldn't be understood the same way as in the next lesson on say history. Domain-specific usages are with us always (well, intermittently). As are school-specific usages; 'define "sentence" ' is banned here, I believe, as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: If you look up "contemporary art", "contemporary dance", "contemporary history", "contemporary classical music", etc in Wikipedia or a domain-specific book (e.g. an encyclopedia of art or music), you'll find the specific meaning it has in different domains. In many contexts it means post 1945, but details vary. It's hard to see how to answer your final question: these are terms of art with specific meanings in specific contexts, but there's quite a few of them.